# How do I optimize my app.js file when using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, laravel-mix

I am looking for help in understanding what are the best practices people are using for a VueJs app that is not an SPA. In my project I have multiple pages and currently I'm treating every page as an SPA. But I'm noticing that my `app.js` size is increases after adding a new page. This is what I have so far

```
require('./bootstrap');
var Vue = require('vue');

import GlobalMixins from './mixins/GlobalMixins'
import VueFlashMessage from 'vue-flash-message'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'
import Treeselect from '@riophae/vue-treeselect'


Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue();        //global event bus


Vue.mixin(GlobalMixins);
Vue.use(PortalVue);
Vue.use(VueFlashMessage,{
    messageOptions: {
        timeout: 7000,
        important: false,
        autoEmit: true,
        pauseOnInteract: true,
        createShortcuts: false,
    }
});

// shared components
Vue.component('navigation', require('./components/navigation.vue').default);
Vue.component('loader',require('./components/shared/custom_loader.vue').default);
Vue.component('treeselect',Treeselect);

//parent components only for each page
Vue.component('goals', require('./components/goals/index.vue').default);
Vue.component('dashboard', require('./components/dashboard/index.vue').default);
Vue.component('twitter', require('./components/twitter/index.vue').default);
Vue.component('trends', require('./components/trends/index.vue').default);
Vue.component('settings', require('./components/settings/index.vue').default);
..........
..........
..........

require('./filters');

window.onload = function () {
    new Vue ({
    el: '#app'
    });
}
```

I'm compiling my assets using `laravel-mix` and even after running `npm run prod` `app.js` size is around 2MB. How can I optimize this?

PS: gzip compression is already enabled on my servers.

Comment: The details fo your question are a bit confusing. You say you're interested in practices that are not SPA, then you say you're building multiple SPA's.  Do you mean you're trying to build a different vue app for each separate page of your website? By default laravel-mix only builds one app per site, if you want to build a different app for each page you'll need to configure mix to build multiple apps.

Comment: just a notice: `dashboard` component gets loaded twice

Comment: @coedycode apologies for any confusion. It may be because I didn't used my analogy for SPA correctly. At the moment what I am looking for is what other ways are there to handle situations like these where you only need have to register the required base component only. Something like on demand registration of components.

Comment: Sounds like you want lazy loading: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html